# Sum rows and duplicate the values

Tags: oracle

I have below records in my oracle database table

```
Id     Amount1  Amount2 Amount3
1101    10       20     30
1102    15       10     20
1103    20       30     35
1104    40       50     60
1105    70       80     90
```

I would like to sum 2nd (1102) and 3rd row (1103) and show the same sum in 2nd and 3rd row.
My result should be as below. How we can be achieved this in oracle query?

```
Id  Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
1101    10  20      30
1102    35  40      55
1103    35  40      55
1104    40  50      60
1105    70  80      90
```

Thank you.

Comment: What ordering determines the 2nd or 3rd row?  Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: I would like to sum the row if the id is 1102 or 1103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using analytic functions. Assuming that `id` is a unique column with values greater than `0`:

```
select
    id,
    amount1,
    amount2,
    sum(amount3) over(partition by case when id in (1102, 1103) then 0 else id end) amount3
from mytable
order by id
```

The window `sum()` assigns a special partition to record where id is `1102` or `1103`, so they are sumed together. Other records remain in their own partition.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56b03169fa054ac2f371446e2e14a480)**:

```
  ID | AMOUNT1 | AMOUNT2 | AMOUNT3
---: | ------: | ------: | ------:
1101 |      10 |      20 |      30
1102 |      15 |      10 |      55
1103 |      20 |      30 |      55
1104 |      40 |      50 |      60
1105 |      70 |      80 |      90
```

Comment: Nice one +1 ... was trying to think of this, but haven't had any coffee yet

Comment: Thank you  so much. This is what I was looking for,